# How to read a specific item in a vector?

Tags: vector, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a viewScope "selection" which is a vector.
I would like to be able to read a specific elementh (third in this case)
I thought dooing it with an iterator like this , but it just gives me all the elements instead of the third...

```
var i = 0;
for (var it = viewScope.selection.iterator();it.hasNext();i++ ) {
  if (i == 3){
    sessionScope.example="item "+i+"="+it.next();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have to say it: This is frankly speaking the weirdest JS loop definition I have ever seen :) Btw: Doesn't this produce an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't really understand your question, but you can get the third element via index, i.e. like

```
viewScope.selection[2]
```

or

```
viewScope.selection.get(2)
```

Comment: I tried that also , and getting an error : "Error while accessing indexed property #'2' on object class java.util.Vector" and for the second one "Error calling method 'get(number)' on java class 'java.util.Vector'"
I think this only works for Arrays

Comment: I'm very sure that should work in SSJS. Did you try it with `get`?

Comment: yes . Then I get "Error calling method 'get(number)' on java class 'java.util.Vector'"

Comment: Could you add the code you use to create the vector to your question?

Comment: I think I found the sollution : viewScope.selection[0][2] seems to work. Strange since I tested the viewscope to see if it's a vector ....